# How is Spring MVC a REST Framework?

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I've seen many examples of what is called Spring REST which basically all are simply Spring MVC.  Granted that using JAXB, and JAXON you can provide XML, and JSON responses, but there is more to REST than just providing text response.

One major issue is that non of these examples mention anything about session; a REST application is supposed to be session-less, but Spring MVC is certainly session-full.

So, does Spring MVC somehow disables session, or are we supposed to disable session when we use Spring MVC to implement REST?

If we are supposed to disable session; then how is it that done?

Comment: we need to handle the sessions ourself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Spring MVC does not enable sessions until you use them;
- I fully agree that the so-called "rest support" in Spring should have been called "pretty urls and Jackson integration", but nowadays it has little market-appeal (even though pretty URLs and JSON are the only thing people associate with REST; that and mapping CRUD to http verbs).
- REST is an architectural choice that has nothing to do with sessions (nor pretty urls, nor json). Since it is more of a religion than an actual technique, nobody will translate it for you to a fixed set of practices. You could have sessions modeled as resources that get created when user logs in and that disappear after some time. And so on.

Comment: Do you have a source that  Spring MVC does not enable sessions until you use them?  I can't find any source that mentions this.  I totally agree with your second statement.  However, for the third statement, session-less is a fundamental properties of a REST web service; if your webapp uses session, then you can't call it REST  at all.

Comment: @user1888243: well, we all have **the** most authoritative source, namely, the sources :-) You can grep it for occurrences of "getSession" and see. Even components like FlashMapManagers try not to open session until it's unavoidable. On the other hand, some technologies that you can use with Spring MVC (like Jasper) do open sessions by default.

Comment: @user1888243: There is no sentence in Fielding's paper that says something remotely like "but remember! even if you follow my words to the letter... if you use a cookie named JSESSIONID, you shall NOT be allowed to call your application RESTful". Application should be "stateless" with respect to what clients see. Behind the facade  I can use any technical means I like, even caching some state and attaching it to some client. And vice versa: even without using session and having prettiest urls possible, I can do a bad, non-restful application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I didn't pay attention to the fact that stateless and session-less are 2 different concepts.

Comment: @user1888243: from purely practical standpoint, add session="false" to your page directive in jsp files :-)